# Keep serialized and compressed Objects in-memory

Tags: java, caching, serialization

I'm currently working on a Part of an Application where "a lot" of data must be selected for further work and I have the impression that the I/O is limiting and not the following work.
My idea is now to have all these objects in memory but serialized an compressed. The question is, if accessing the objects like this would be faster than direct Database access and if it is a good idea or not. (and if it is feasble in terms of memory consumption = serialized form uses less memory than normal object)

EDIT February 2011:

The creation of the objects is the slow part and not the database access itself. Having all in memory is not possible and using ehcache option to "overflow to disk" is actually slower than just getting the data from the database. Standard java serialization is also unusable. it is also a lot slower. So basically nothing I can do about it...

Comment: several thousand rows in my "test case" it's 30k rows. The thing is that it's a list of IDs (primary keys) that can be anything from 1 to 30k or more. I initially just created a huge SQL IN Clause. Actually worked fine excpet that it easly consumes several GB of memory. I now select each element separatley. Of course that had a negative impact but a pretty small one compared to 10 times less memory usage. It's a special search hence should be "fast".

Comment: Have you tried a custom serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compressed serialized form will use less memory, if it is a large object.  However for smaller objects e.g. which use primtives. The original object will be much smaller.

I would first check whether you really need to do this. e.g. Can you just consume more memory? or restructure your objects so they use less memory.

Comment: The objects are very heavy-weight and reasonable number won't fit in a reasonable amount of memory. Object is from a library so I can't restructure them.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically looking for an in-memory cache or an in-memory datagrid.  There are plenty of APIs/products for this sort of thing.  ehcache/hibernate chace/gridgain etc etc

Comment: I found ehcache, I assume it can be used without hibernate?

Comment: @beginner_ My understanding is that yes it can be used stand alone

Comment: I looked at the ehcache homepage but didn't not find an answer to following question: Does it cache the whole object or some kind of compressed form?

Comment: @beginner_ I imagine it would be a compressed version of some sort.  I'm sure there are some efficiencies over the .class format / bytecode in memory.  This is however getting behind my limited expertise.

Comment: I've looked a bit at Ehcache but it seems a little too complicated for my usage scenario and code examples on the site are old and/or broken. It's a pitty because examples are the most helpful thin if they work.

Answer (score 0):

"I have the impression that the I/O is limiting and not the following work. " -> I would be very sure of this before starting implementing such a thing.

The simpler approach I can suggest you is to use ehcache with the option to store on disk when the size of the cache get too big.

Another completely different approach could be using some doc based nosql db like couchdb to store objects selected "for further work"

Comment: The I/O on this case is a HSQLDB with cached dataTables meaning disk access. I have a separate thread for reading from the database and one for doing the work. Reading/selecting is done in smaller batches and populates a queue so they work in parallel. Because of that I can see that the "reading thread" is active 100 % of the time while the other one is waiting for it like 80% of the time. However might be different with different RDBMS.

Comment: I used Hypersonic several years ago and it was very good for fast developing but I don't remember it as being particularly fast. I'd rather suggest you to try couchdb or mongodb or maybe ehcache/terracotta.

Comment: Ignore my above comment about ehcache. Got it running rather quickly. You just need some common sense to correct errors in example code. Anyway speed of the operation increase about 10x if everything is in cache. Objects don't seem to be compressed because memory usage is unacceptable high. But you might still be right. The actually time consuming part could be the creation of the object and the parsing of the data and not the actually reading of the data (longvarchar). of course these steps happen after each other.